# Disabling a toolbarbutton when there is no page to go back - Firefox extension

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I need to disable a toolbar button when there is no page to go back in history object. Similar to the browser back button.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use [`tabbrowser.sessionHistory` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tabbrowser#p-sessionHistory):

```
gBrowser.sessionHistory.addSHistoryListener(myListener);
```

Your listener should check whether `gBrowser.sessionHistory.index` is 0 (nothing to go back) and set `button.disabled` property appropriately.

Either that or you simply make your button observe the browser's back button using [`<observes>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/observes):

```
<toolbarbutton ...>
  <observes element="Browser:Back" attribute="disabled"/>
</toolbarbutton>
```

This makes sure that the `disabled` attribute for your button is copied over from the `Browser:Back` command.

Comment: I used gBrowser.canGoBack and gBrowser.canGoForward instead along with <observes>